# Making one usb headset work with two computers

Tags: usb, computers

I have a question about connecting one Logitech USB headset to work with two computers at the same time.  I would think this would be able to be accomplished in the same kind of way a KVM works but not sure.  I tried the basics of just splicing a usb cable together so it has two male ends and one female end.  This did not work so what I did was make it so one computer powers the usb headset and the data is sent down both lines.

Neither of these methods worked.  Does anyone have ideas on how to do this, cheaply, so i can use one headset across two computers?

Comment: Wow. Here's the reason we implement output driver protection circuitry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This won't work, and will not be a good idea for the PCs.

USB 2.0 (the most commonly used at the moment) is a half duplex differential bus, which means that the host and device take it in turns to send/receive. The host (PC in your case) initiates all transactions, which means the device must wait for a signal from the host if it has data to send.

If you have two hosts on the same bus, they will both be trying to send data at the same time and things will get very confused. Plus it may put undue stress on the output drivers, as they will be fighting against each other (known as bus contention) USB is quite tolerant of problems like this, so it's unlikely you have damaged anything.

If you were comitted to doing this, you would probably have to design your own adapter (using a couple of microcontrollers, FTDI chips, or similar)

Far easier is to go analogue as Chris suggests, this would only require a simple mixing circuit.
Or transmit audio data from one PC to the other, combine and then send to headset.

EDIT - for an analogue mixing circuit:

For the microphone, you would hope that the internal amplifier might be low impedance enough to drive both PC inputs okay. However, many simple electret circuit are pretty high impedance, so you might want to use a simple opamp buffer:

[image: audio buffer]

The opamp can be another similar part, and the +9V can be less/more depending on what you have available. You might want to use the existing power from the PC (5V?) that powers the electret, and use a low voltage single rail opamp.
Before you try any of this, I'd just connect straight to each PC mic input and see if the quality is reasonable.

The headphone drivers are the trickier part, these certainly need to be mixed properly, or they will attempt to drive each other. Something like this should work quite well:

[image: Mix Headphone]

This only shows one channel, you will have to duplicate for the other one. The grounds must be tied together also (not shown on schematic)
Depending on how big your headphones are, you may need to use something like an LM386, or you may be able to drive directly (especially if you pick a high current opamp)
Google for "LM386 headphone amp" and you will get overloaded with circuits.

Comment: When making an analog headset between two computers, would just Y cables work for the mic and earpeices where you would just rely on the computers to mute and adjust volume or would you need some sort of circuit board to prevent any issues.  If you would need a circuit, what would that look like?

Comment: You need at least some sort of basic mixing circuit. A little busy right this second, but I'll edit the answer shortly with some more details.

Comment: @bretterer - edited answer with some more info. If this looks a bit like too much trouble, I'm sure there are various battery powered mixing boxes available.

Answer (score 3):

Use an analog headset and some capacitors or other simple mixer circuit.

USB does not support dual mastering.  If you really want to use this, you will need a software solution to combine the data from the two computers.

That could be in the form of some monstrosity with two USB device ports and one USB host port... but much more realistic would be to capture the output audio on one computer and ship it over the network to be mixed into the audio playing on the other, then plug the headset into that computer.

If you have to plug in as USB headsets, you would probably be better off grafting the circuitry of two USB headsets together with analog mixing at the speaker outputs than trying to find or make a USB combiner device.  USB sound cards are also inexpensively available and might be an option, again mixing their analog outputs.

Comment: sounds good for my final year project.